# Tomar la primer letra de cada nombre en mayuscula con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito tomar la primer letra de cada nombre o apellido que viene en un arreglo y me lo ponga en mayuscula, ejemplo:

Roberto Rodriguez = RR
Ezquiel fernandez =  EF

gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Comment: con este array -> `let arr = ["roberto rodriguez", "ezquiel fernandez"];` y luego -> `let result = arr.map(name => name.split(" ").map(word=>word[0].toUpperCase()) .join("")).join(", ");`, haces log a `result` y lo tienes, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la primer letra de una cadena mediante `charAt(0)`, entonces la concatenas con la primera letra que se encuentra después del primer espacio utilizando `indexOf(" ") + 1` y al final lo unes todo utilizando `join(" , ")`.

```js
let nombres = ["Roberto Rodriguez", "Ezquiel Fernandez"];
let nombresMayuscula = nombres.map(nombre => nombre.charAt(0) + nombre.charAt(nombre.indexOf(" ") + 1)).join(" , ");
console.log(nombresMayuscula); // "RR EF"
```

Donde:

`[R]oberto [R]odriguez` => `RR`

`[E]zquiel [F]ernandez` => `EF`

Comment: gracias me funciono perfectamente!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar utilizando los métodos de un string y en este caso de los arrays, te comparto un ejemplo, seguramente lo puedes mejorar:

```
fullname
  .split(' ')
  .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
  .join('')
```